# Retrieve the "out degree" of every vertex of a digraph (jgrapht)

Tags: java, processing, jgrapht, digraphs

I have a digraph created using:

```
public static DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
public static Point firstPoint = new Point(2, 7);
```

Vertices and edges were created with a Flood Fill algorithm implemented in a matrix. In the matrix I use, there are only 0s, 1s and 2s. The Flood fill algorithm detects if there is a loop formed by 1s and 2s, and as it goes through the 1s, it turns them into 3s. Example:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Will Become:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 3 0 0 
0 0 0 3 3 3 0 3 0 0 
0 0 0 3 0 0 3 3 0 0 
0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

As the algorithm goes through the Matrix, it creates vertices (each 1 it encounters) and edges (between two consecutive points). Here is the Algorithm, which starts at the point (2,7) in the matrix:

```
    public static class FloodFill {


     public static void resolution(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Found loop: "+checkIfPositionIsInLoop(matrix, 2, 7, 3));


    //result
    System.out.println("-------------------"); 

    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }

  private static Direction direction;

  public static boolean checkIfPositionIsInLoop(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int fillValue) {
    int targetX = x;
    int targetY = y;

    return fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, x, y, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.LEFT );
  }

  private static boolean fillReachesTargetPosition(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY, int fillValue, Direction forbiddenDirection) {

    if (x>=matrix.length)
      return false;
    if (y>=matrix[x].length)
      return false;

    int originValue=matrix[x][y];
    matrix[x][y]=fillValue;

    int xToFillNext;
    int yToFillNext;

    boolean fillingReachedTargetPosition = false;

    // Up
    xToFillNext = x-1;
    yToFillNext = y;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.UP)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      return true;
    } else if (xToFillNext>=0 && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.UP)) {  
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);   
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.DOWN );
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Right
    xToFillNext = x;
    yToFillNext = y+1;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX  && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      return true;
    } else if (yToFillNext<matrix[xToFillNext].length && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.LEFT );
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Down
    xToFillNext = x+1;
    yToFillNext = y;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      return true;
    } else if (xToFillNext<matrix.length  && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.UP );  
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Left
    xToFillNext = x;
    yToFillNext = y-1;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      return true;
    } else if (yToFillNext>=0 && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.LEFT)) {

      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.RIGHT );
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

So each Point object/vertex doesn't have an identifier I can use like:

```
directedGraph.outDegreeOf(firstPoint);
directedGraph.outDegreeOf(secondPoint);
```

And I'd like to print the number of outwards edges of each vertex. I found this function in the jgrapht library:

```
directedGraph.outDegreeOf(Point);
```

So I tried to go through the vertex set as I would go through a list (in my Draw method which keeps looping in Processing, meaning that while the program is running, the Draw method keeps on being executed). Here is my draw method and the circuitState() method that starts the Flood Fill (I normally use Reactivision to add elements to the matrix: each marker detected appears as a 1 in the matrix, but to test it I created a matrix):

```
void draw() {


  matrix [1][5]= 2;
  matrix [1][6]= 2;
  matrix [2][5]= 2;
  matrix [2][6]= 2;
  matrix [3][5]=1;
  matrix [2][7]=1;
  matrix [4][6]=1;
  matrix [3][5]=1;
  matrix [4][6]=1;
  matrix [4][7]=0;
  matrix [3][4]=1;
  matrix [3][3]=1;
  matrix [3][7]=1;
  matrix [3][7]=1;
  matrix [3][7]=1;
  matrix [4][3]=1;
  matrix [5][3]=1;
  matrix [5][4]=1;
  matrix [5][5]=1;
  matrix [5][6]=1;
  matrix [4][7]=1;
  matrix [6][6]=1;
  matrix [7][6]=1;
  matrix [3][2]=1;
  matrix [3][1]=1;
  matrix [3][0]=1;

  // Print Matrix
  for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
      System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
  System.out.print("\n");

  // This part detects the fiducial markers 
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 
  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0; i<tuioObjectList.size (); i++) {

    //System.out.println("#vertex: "+ directedGraph.vertexSet());

    TuioObject tobj= tuioObjectList.get(i);
    stroke(0);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
    rotate(tobj.getAngle());
    rect(-80, -40, 80, 40);
    popMatrix();
    fill(255);
    x = round(10*tobj.getX ());
    y = round(10*tobj.getY ());
    iD = tobj.getSymbolID();
    // directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(x,y));
    int taille = fiducialsList.length;
    for (int o = 0; o<taille; o++) {
      if (iD == o) { 
        myType = fiducialsList [o];
      }
    } 

    activList.add(new Fiducial (x, y, iD, myType));
    matrix [x][y] = 1 ;
    circuitState ();
    for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
      for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[p][r] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
  System.out.println("#vertices: "+ directedGraph.vertexSet());
  System.out.println("#edges: "+ directedGraph.edgeSet());
  //Re-initialize matrix
  for (int[] row : matrix)
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);

  for (int z= 0; z < directedGraph.vertexSet ().size(); z++)
  {
    directedGraph.outDegreeOf(myPoint);
  }
}
void circuitState () {
  if ( matrix [2][7]==1 ) {
    FloodFill.resolution(args);
    if (matrix [3][5]== 3) {
      System.out.println("Fermé");
    } else {
      long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
      timeSpent.add(new Time (time));
      System.out.println(" Ouvert " + "took" + estimatedTime);
    }
  }
}
```

But it can't find the Point object that I created with this class:

```
public static class Point {

  public int x;
  public int y;

  public  Point(int x, int y) 
  {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[x="+x+" y="+y+"]");
  }

  @Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.y;
    return hash;
}



@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) 
{
    if (this == other)
       return true;

    if (!(other instanceof Point))
       return false;

    Point otherPoint = (Point) other;
    return otherPoint.x == x && otherPoint.y == y;
}
}
```

Is there a more simple way to do this ? If not, what am I missing to allow the other method to use the Point object ? (what's weird is that I use the Point object is other methods and it works fine so why the Draw method can't access it ?)
I use processing which is based on Java

Comment: Instead of posting disconnected snippets, you'll have much better luck if you post a single [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and paste to see your exact error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Needed to add:

```
for(Point myPoint : directedGraph.vertexSet()){
   int degree = directedGraph.outDegreeOf(myPoint);
   System.out.println("Degree of " myPoint.toString() + ": " + degree);
}
```

Works fine with this

Answer (score 2):

Look at your for loop:

```
for (int z= 0; z < directedGraph.vertexSet().size(); z++)
{
    directedGraph.outDegreeOf(Point);
}
```

This syntax doesn't make any sense:

```
directedGraph.outDegreeOf(Point);
```

`Point` is a **class**. You need to pass an **instance** of that class into the `outDegreeOf()` function. It might look something like this:

```
Point p = new Point(1, 6);
int degree = directedGraph.outDegreeOf(p);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Point is also an object, shouldn't it work with it ? I've updated my question to make it more clear: I've created Point objects as the Flood Fill algorithm goes through the matrix so it didn't create objects with a "name"/identifier as you did in your example with "Point p = new Point(1, 6);". So I can't do this in outDegreeOf()

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick My code is just an example. you need to get the instances of `Point`that you want to get the `outDegreeOf` yourself. I'm not sure what actual `Point` instances you want to use.

Comment: Ok but when I do it with myPoint which would be my equivalent of you p Point, it still can't be found

Comment: You're going to have to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's impossible to help you if we can't see the real, actual code you're running. What exactly is `myPoint`? What exactly is in your graph already?

Comment: I posted more code. I had to add a myPoint object in the flood fill algorithm to create a new vertex each times it reaches a spot in the matrix. In my graph I have all the 1s on the matrix which are vertices, and edges between each 1 connected.

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick And what does that code do? Note that you never actually do anything with the result of the `outDegreeOf()` function, so I'm not sure what you expect to happen?

Comment: I should add System.out.println( directedGraph.outDegreeOf(...));, I want to print the number for each element. And once I figure out to make it work, I can use if statements etc to make it useful. 
The draw method is executed, calls the circuitState() which if a condition is fulfilled, starts the FloodFill algorithm in the Matrix at the point (2,7). The algorithm, while going through the matrix, creates vertices and edges with 1s.

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick What does your code do? What do you expect it to do? What is the difference between those two things?